# Is it possible to make HTML code output as text on my website?

Tags: html

For example, if I were trying to add the text `<div class="Hello"> </div>` (without the added spaces) to my website so that it would output as text instead of being considered another class?

Comment: What do you mean by "being considered as another class"? Do you want the tags themselves rendered as text? If thats the case you need to use HTML entities `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks for your help.  I apologize for the poor wording in my original question!

Answer (score 1):

The angle brackets define html tags. [HTML Entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) are used to replace special characters with a text representation.

For your example you would want:

```
&lt;div class="Hello"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
```

Which would render as `<div class="Hello"> </div>`